# Errors when following Husky UR5 Mobile Manipulation Demo (Simulation) tutorial for ROS indigo

Tags: ros, husky, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Ubuntu 14.04 ROS indigo It is in Simulation
I am following your great tutorial on [Husky UR5 Mobile Manipulation Demo (Simulation)](http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/husky/HuskyManip.html)

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-husky-simulator && sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-husky-ur5-moveit-config
mkdir -p devel_ws/src && cd devel_ws/src && catkin_init_workspace
git clone https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot && cd ..
catkin_make install
source ~/devel_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

However, when I was trying to Bring up Gazebo And The Husky with the following command:

Running the launch file which will bring up Gazebo with the Husky + UR5.

6.roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_playpen.launch ur5_enabled:=true

It throws errors as below. Can you please help?

```
ted@vra1:~/devel_ws$ roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_playpen.launch ur5_enabled:=true
... logging to /home/ted/.ros/log/52c54970-156e-11ea-b2c3-4c72b923f66b/roslaunch-vra1-13491.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py", line 62, in <module>
    xacro.main()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 696, in main
    eval_self_contained(doc)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 626, in eval_self_contained
    eval_all(doc.documentElement, macros, symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 553, in eval_all
    eval_all(body, macros, scoped)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 553, in eval_all
    eval_all(body, macros, scoped)
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 497, in eval_all
    result = eval_text(at[1], symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 483, in eval_text
    results.append(handle_expr(lex.next()[1][2:-1]))
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 470, in handle_expr
    return eval_expr(lex, symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 444, in eval_expr
    result = eval_term(lex, symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 418, in eval_term
    result = eval_factor(lex, symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 398, in eval_factor
    return neg * eval_lit(lex, symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 369, in eval_lit

    raise XacroException("Property wasn't defined: %s" % str(ex))
xacro.XacroException: Property wasn't defined: u'pi'
while processing /opt/ros/indigo/share/husky_gazebo/launch/husky_empty_world.launch:
while processing /opt/ros/indigo/share/husky_gazebo/launch/spawn_husky.launch:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py '/opt/ros/indigo/share/husky_gazebo/urdf/description.gazebo.xacro'     laser_enabled:=true     ur5_enabled:=true     kinect_enabled:=false     ] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(arg husky_gazebo_description)'     laser_enabled:=$(arg laser_enabled)     ur5_enabled:=$(arg ur5_enabled)     kinect_enabled:=$(arg kinect_enabled)     " name="robot_description"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
ted@vra1:~/devel_ws$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339016/errors-when-following-husky-ur5-mobile-manipulation-demo-(simulation)-tutorial-for-ros-indigo/) by [stevensu1838](https://answers.ros.org/users/32486/stevensu1838/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2019-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: I just noticed that link to the Husky Dual Arm manipulation demo, not the general Husky + UR5 page.

The dual arm manipulation demo page asks you to `git clone https://github.com/DualUR5Husky/universal_robot`, *not* the upstream repository.

---

Original answer:

Seeing as you're using Indigo (which is EOL btw) and you do this:

> ```
> git clone https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot && cd ..
> ```

it's likely you're trying to use the Kinetic version of the `universal_robot` packages on Indigo.

That won't work in this case.

You could try to switch to the `indigo-devel` branch:

```
cd $HOME/devel_ws/src/universal_robot
git checkout indigo-devel
```

Then rebuild your workspace and try again.

Note (again): ROS Indigo (and Ubuntu Trusty) are end-of-life and no longer supported. Neither are the packages in `indigo-devel` of `universal_robot`. It may work, or it may not. There are no guarantees.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevensu1838](https://answers.ros.org/users/32486/stevensu1838/) on 2019-12-03**:
Hi all,
It was my bad that I linked the wrong husky manipulation tutorial, and it's been revised to the general Husky + UR5 page. I could run the dual arm manipulation demo page with no problem. It only throw errors when I run general Husky + UR5 page. Thanks a lot

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-03**:
My answer would be the same: make sure you're using the correct branch.

**Comment by [stevensu1838](https://answers.ros.org/users/32486/stevensu1838/) on 2019-12-03**:
Hi, your solution works for the general Husky + UR5 page. Now I can run the launch file which will bring up Gazebo with the Husky + UR5 by the following line:
roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_playpen.launch ur5_enabled:=true

However, the thing is the husky robot is upside down swinging on the ground. And the robotic hand on UR5 is missing. Any chance you know why? Thanks a million.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-03**:
No sorry, I wouldn't know.